# Stored Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a piece of code that calls a SQL Server stored procedure, but I keep an error of "too many arguments specified".

Here is my SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_update_consequenceweighting]
    @ITID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CW AS INT 

    SELECT 
        @CW = Impact_Type_Weighting 
    FROM
        tbl_ImpactType 
    WHERE
        ImpactTypeID = @ITID

    UPDATE 
        Tbl_Consequences
    SET
        Consequence_Weighting = @CW
    WHERE
        Impact_TypeID = @ITID
END
```

This is the code in MS Access that calls the stored procedure:

```
Private Sub Combo13_LostFocus()

Dim P1 As Integer

P1 = Forms![Frm_Ws10a]![Frm_WS10b]![Combo13].Column(0)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

Dim adstring As Variant

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection

CN.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQL 
Server;Server=LDXFBHD013492\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=YES;"
CN.Open

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = CN
        .CommandText = "dbo.usp_update_consequenceweighting"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Refresh
        Set prm = .CreateParameter("@ITID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
       .Parameters.Append prm
       prm.Value = P1

    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Me.Recalc
    Me.Refresh

Set prm = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please help. This use to work with DAO but then I got the conflict between 32 and 64 bit drivers.

Comment: It that VB or VB.NET or something?

Comment: Your parameter is an integer, but you are creating the parameter as varchar.

Comment: Also it looks like you don't need to refresh parameters by using .Parameters.Refresh here. Like described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436061/stored-procedure-using-parameters refresh will add parameters automatically and then you're adding your parameter manually one more time

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have removed the parameters.refresh and the error went away I also changed the the parameter to a adinteger. Now it doesnt seem the stored procedure is being called ???